# How can I simplify a long javascript switch case statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below. It looks long and complicated and now I have to add some more conditions. Is there any way I can simplify this code. All I can think of is combining the City and Menu switches but then if I do that I have to do get the pk value one way for City and another way for Menu. Does javascript offer any other way to do the same thing as a switch? Sorry for the long code listing but I thought I should include everything.

```
function getParams(entity) {

 var store = window.localStorage;
 var table = "Content";

 switch (entity) {
    case "City":
        if (store.getItem('AccountID')) {
            pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + "04" + "000";
            return {
                pk: pk,
                param: '?pk=' + pk,
                table: table,
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account");
            return { rc: false }
        }
        break;
    case "Menu":
        if (store.getItem('AccountID')) {
            pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + "00" + "000";
            return { 
                pk: pk,
                param: '?pk=' + pk,
                table: table,
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account");
            return { rc: false }
        }
        break;
    case "Page":
        if (store.getItem('AccountID') && store.getItem('PageID')) {
            pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + store.getItem('PageID') + "000";
            return {
                pk: pk,
                param: '?pk=' + pk,
                table: table,
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account and Page Type");
            return { rc: false }
        }
        break;
    case "Question":
        if (store.getItem('AccountID') &&
            store.getItem('CityID') && 
            store.getItem('TopicID') ) {
            pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + store.getItem('CityID');
            return {
                pk: pk,
                param: '?pk=' + pk + '&rk=' + store.getItem('TopicID'),
                table: "Question",
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account, City and Topic");
            return { rc: false }
        }
        break;
    case "Reference":
        if (store.getItem('ReferenceID')) {
            pk = store.getItem('ReferenceID');
            return { 
                pk: pk,
                param: '?pk=' + pk,
                table: "Reference",
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Reference");
            return { rc: false }
        }
        break;
    case "Topic":
        if (store.getItem('AccountID') && store.getItem('CityID')) {
            pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + "05" + store.getItem('CityID');
            return { 
                pk: pk,
                param: parameters = '?pk=' + pk,
                table: table,
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account and City");
            return { rc: false }
        }
        break;
    default:
        ;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: keep it DRY, you could easily write a function to do the blocks within each case statement

Comment: u deffo can check for store.getItem('AccountID') before switch

Comment: Sorry I didn't even know about codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Difficult since you are doing completely different things in all the cases... though your error hadling (paramOnFailure) could be moved - just set a 'failure' flag and handle that after the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this part of you code in function and call it with the proper parameter

```
  if (store.getItem('AccountID')) {
             pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + "00" + "000";
             return {
                  pk: pk,
                 param: '?pk=' + pk,
                 table: table,
                 rc: true
             }
         } else {
             paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account");
             return { rc: false }
         }
```

So you code will be somthing like this and call this function from each Switch Case

```
function CommonforCase(store,value)
{
   if (store.getItem('AccountID')) {
                 pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + value;
                 return {
                      pk: pk,
                     param: '?pk=' + pk,
                     table: table,
                     rc: true
                 }
             } else {
                 paramOnFailure("Please reselect Account");
                 return { rc: false }
             } 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it were me I'd move the code from each case condition into their own functions. This should make things more legible.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function getTheItem(itemName, value, table){
         if (store.getItem(itemName)) {
            pk = store.getItem(itemName) + value;
            return {
                pk: pk,
                param: '?pk=' + pk,
                table: table,
                rc: true
            }
        } else {
            paramOnFailure("Please reselect"+ itemName);
            return { rc: false }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not scroll done at first, so I missed a lot of that switch statement (this might also be the case in some of the other answers). The first two cases are straightforward to factor out into a function. In the rest of your code, you have more differences, so you would need more arguments in that function, which can easily get confusing.

So instead, you could use a [configuration object](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449399115/functions/configuration_objects) to have named options and use default values (for merging default and given values, see [.extend()](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.extend) and [merging objects dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)). You could also build up the error message dynamically from all mandatory values. It should become shorter and more readable this way.

Some pseudo-code:

```
// Pseudo-Code
function getParams(entity) {
 var store = window.localStorage;
 var defaults = {
    "mandatoryValues":[],
    "pk":null,
    "table":"Content",
    "errorMessage":"Please reselect Account",
    "param":""
 };
 var foo = function(cfgObj) {
    // Add default values from defaults variable for missing properties in cfgObj
    // Set other missing values based on cfgObj (e.g. `param` from `pk`)
    // Return your object using the now 'complete' cfgObj
 }

 switch (entity) {
    case "City":
        var pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + "04" + "000";
        return foo(
            "mandatoryValues":[store.getItem('AccountID')],
            "pk":pk);
    // Menu, Page
    case "Question":
        var pk = store.getItem('AccountID') + store.getItem('CityID');
        return foo(
            "mandatoryValues":[
                store.getItem('AccountID'),
                store.getItem('CityID'),
                store.getItem('TopicID')],
            "pk":pk,
            "param":'?pk=' + pk + '&rk=' + store.getItem('TopicID'),
            "table":"Question");
    // Reference, Topic, default
}
```